# Listview displaying redundant data

Tags: c#, listview, redundancy

I have the following code in which I am adding data to a list view but I end up having redundant items in it. Please let me know where am I going wrong

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\sample.txt");
        string s;
        s = sr.ReadLine();

        while (s != null)
        {
            s = sr.ReadLine();
            var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^([a-zA-Z._]+)@([\d]+)");

            if(m.Success)
            {
                allcont ac = new allcont();
                ac.name = m.Groups[1].Value;
                ac.number = m.Groups[2].Value;
                con.Add(ac);
                foreach (allcont aa in con)
                {
                    ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(new string[] { aa.name, aa.number });
                    i.Tag = aa;
                    listView1.Items.Add(i);
                }
                s = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
    contacts con = new contacts();
    public class contacts:List<allcont>
    { 

    }
    public class allcont
    {
        public string name;
        public string number;
    }
}
```

My **sample.txt** has this:

```
wer@123

erty@098

sdf@645

ytu@432
```

**Update**: This is the data my list view shows:

```
name number    
wer  123
wer  123
erty 098
wer  123
erty 098
sdf  645
wer  123
erty 098
sdf  645
wer  123
erty 098
sdf  645
ytu  432
```

Comment: What does the list look like? *Redundant* can be a number of things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you get something like

```
wer@123

wer@123
erty@098

wer@123
erty@098
sdf@645

wer@123
erty@098
sdf@645
ytu@432
```

Reason : you've got a problem here

```
allcont ac = new allcont();
ac.name = m.Groups[1].Value;
ac.number = m.Groups[2].Value;
con.Add(ac);
foreach (allcont aa in con)
{
     ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(new string[] { aa.name, aa.number });
     i.Tag = aa;
     listView1.Items.Add(i);
 }
```

because you do this in the while loop. (you're adding things to the list `con` at each loop, and then loop this "incremented list" inside the while loop).

So you should move the "inner loop"

```
foreach (allcont aa in con)
    {
         ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(new string[] { aa.name, aa.number });
         i.Tag = aa;
         listView1.Items.Add(i);
     }
```

outside of the while loop (after the `sr.Close`)

Answer (score 1):

```
con.Add(ac);
                foreach (allcont aa in con)
                {
                    ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(new string[] { aa.name, aa.number });
                    i.Tag = aa;
                    listView1.Items.Add(i);
                }
```

you are iterating full con collection on every match
get rid of the inner loop

```
allcont ac = new allcont();
ac.name = m.Groups[1].Value;
ac.number = m.Groups[2].Value;
con.Add(ac);

ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem(new string[] { ac.name, ac.number });
i.Tag = aa;
listView1.Items.Add(i);
```